# Making histogram with Spark DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to make a histogram with a column from a dataframe which looks like

```
DataFrame[C0: int, C1: int, ...]
```

If I were to make a histogram with the column C1, what should I do?

Some things I have tried are

```
df.groupBy("C1").count().histogram()
df.C1.countByValue()
```

Which do not work because of mismatch in data types.

Answer (score 20):

The [pyspark_dist_explore](https://github.com/Bergvca/pyspark_dist_explore/) package that @Chris van den Berg mentioned is quite nice. If you prefer not to add an additional dependency you can use this bit of code to plot a simple histogram.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Show histogram of the 'C1' column
bins, counts = df.select('C1').rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).histogram(20)

# This is a bit awkward but I believe this is the correct way to do it 
plt.hist(bins[:-1], bins=bins, weights=counts)
```

Answer (score 16):

What worked for me is

```
df.groupBy("C1").count().rdd.values().histogram()
```

I have to convert to RDD because I found `histogram` method in  pyspark.RDD class, but not in spark.SQL module

Comment: Does this approach allow you to set bin size?

Answer (score 14):

You can use `histogram_numeric` Hive UDAF:

```
import random

random.seed(323)

sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
n = 3  # Number of buckets
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    sc.parallelize(enumerate(random.random() for _ in range(1000))),
   ["id", "v"]
)

hists = df.selectExpr("histogram_numeric({0}, {1})".format("v", n))

hists.show(1, False)
## +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
## |histogram_numeric(v,3)                                                              |
## +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
## |[[0.2124888140177466,415.0], [0.5918851340384337,330.0], [0.8890271451209697,255.0]]|
## +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You can also extract the column of interest and use `histogram` method on `RDD`:

```
df.select("v").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).histogram(n)
## ([0.002028109534323752,
##  0.33410233677189705,
##  0.6661765640094703,
##  0.9982507912470436],
## [327, 326, 347])
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that `histogram_numeric` does not guarantee evenly-spaced bins -- this surprised me, anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say your values in C1 are between 1-1000 and you want to get a histogram of 10 bins. You can do something like:
df.withColumn("bins", df.C1/100).groupBy("bins").count()
If your binning is more complex you can make a UDF for it (and at worse, you might need to analyze the column first, e.g. by using describe or through some other method).

Comment: Don't forget to cast it as `int` otherwise you'll get as many groups as before

Answer (score 2):

If you want a to plot the Histogram, you could use the [pyspark_dist_explore](https://github.com/Bergvca/pyspark_dist_explore) package:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
hist(ax, df.groupBy("C1").count().select("count"))
```

If you would like the data in a pandas DataFrame you could use:

```
pandas_df = pandas_histogram(df.groupBy("C1").count().select("count"))
```

Answer (score -1):

One easy way could be

```
import pandas as pd
x = df.select('symboling').toPandas()  # symboling is the column for histogram
x.plot(kind='hist')
```

Comment: This approach can be used for small datasets, otherwise it is suboptimal