# How to build a histogram in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a large pyspark dataframe and want a histogram of one of the columns.

I can do:

```
df.select.("col").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).histogram(100)
```

but this is very slow, seems to convert the dataframe to an rdd, and I am not even sure why I need the flatMap.

What is the best/fastest way to achieve this?

Comment: You only need `flatMap` is your column contain nested values. Refer to this question for other ways : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36043256/making-histogram-with-spark-dataframe-column

Answer (score -7):

convert your data frame to pandas data frame as

```
df_pd = df.toPandas()
```

then use,

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df_pd.hist(column='column name')
```

This should work

Comment: Conversion to Pandas DataFrame is very inefficient and also not guaranteed working in low memory environments.

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:pyspark]; it can be assumed that OP wants a response that solves a problem using this specific technology. Generating histogram data outwith [tag:pyspark] is not relevant.