# Hive 3.1.2 UDAFs not working in Spark 3.0.0

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive, hiveql, user-defined-functions

`pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: No handler for UDF/UDAF/UDTF 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDAFHistogramNumeric': java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.SimpleGenericUDAFParameterInfo.<init>([Lorg.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspector;, boolean, boolean); line 4 pos 29`

I get the above error when I try to use histogram_numeric from Hive in Spark SQL.

I've included the relevant `hive-exec` jar, enabled hive support and I'm starting to wonder if this isn't supported at the moment.

Hive version: 3.1.2
Spark version: 3.0.0

If someone has a simple snippet which works for them when registering Hive UDAFs in Spark 3.0.0 that would be super useful too

Comment: Can you share a sample code snippet for what you are trying to do?

Comment: I tried running following code snippet on Spark 3.0.0 and it worked without any errors.  https://www.codepile.net/pile/OQK1024M. Are you trying to do something similar or is your question about something else entirely, do update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to register hive uadf via hiveCtx.udf.registerJavaUDAF, but no luck.

```
hiveCtx.udf.registerJavaUDAF("histogram_numeric", "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDAFHistogramNumeric")
```

The hive class which implements "histogram_numeric" was there, but it doesn't conform to spark's JavaUADF interface.

But I found the code with dataframe's selectExpr works. I don't know why.

```
users_spark_df.selectExpr('histogram_numeric(age, 2)')
```

[Making histogram with Spark DataFrame column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36043256/making-histogram-with-spark-dataframe-column)

Comment: selectExpr gives me the same errors. I did not know Spark had it's own histogram functions though, which I think will serve my purpose