# Spark Dataframe : Group by custom Range

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, databricks

I have a Spark Dataframe which I aggregated based on a column called "Rank", with "Sum" beging the Sum of all values with that Rank.

`df.groupBy("Rank").agg(sum("Col1")).orderBy("Rank").show()`

| Rank | Sum(Col1) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1523 |
| 2 | 785 |
| 3 | 232 |
| 4 | 69 |
| 5 | 126 |
| ... | .... |
| 430 | 7 |

Instead of having the Sum for every single value of "Rank", I would like to group my data into rank "buckets", to get a more compact output. For example :

| Rank Range | Sum(Col1) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1523 |
| 2-5 | 1212 |
| 5-10 | ... |
| ... | ... |
| 100+ | .... |

Instead of having 4 different rows for Rank 2,3,4,5 - I would like to have one row "2-5" showing the sum for all these ranks.
What would be the best way of doing that ? I am quite new to Spark Dataframes and am thankful for any help and especially examples on how to achieve that

Thank you !

Comment: You didn't mention if this is scala/python

Answer (score 1):

Few options:

1. Histogram - build a histogram. See the following post:
   [Making histogram with Spark DataFrame column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36043256/making-histogram-with-spark-dataframe-column/36060072)
2. Add another column for the bucket values (See [Apache spark dealing with case statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39982135/apache-spark-dealing-with-case-statements)):

```
df.select(when(people("Rank Range") === "1", "1")
     .when(..., "2-5")
     .otherwise("100"))
```

Now you can run your group by query on the new `Rank Range` column.